# Zend Framework Send Mail

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

Is it possible to send array values as body of the zend mail.For example,

```
$mail=new Zend_Mail();
$params=$this->getRequest()->getParams();
$mail->setSubject('Order products');
$mail->addTo('recipient@gmail.com','Recipient');
$mail->setBodyText($params['products']); // $params['products'] array
$mail->setFrom('someone@gmail.com','Name');
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, how would poor `Zend_Mail` know how to deal with an array? Just `implode()` and/or format it in your desired way before sending.

Answer (score 1):

You will have always an empty body this way, you need to convert your array into String

The BodyText is an object(Zend_Mime_Part), along with other information this object contains a content field, the problem is : befor adding the content to the mime_part object it passes throu rtrim(), so as result you will have an empty string passed as content.

rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, ....\library\Zend\Mime.php on line 170

Answer (score 0):

i used this way and it worked for me..

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom('someone@gmail.com');
$mail->setBodyHtml($oForm->getValue('text'));
$mail->addTo(array('xyz.aaa@web.com', 'eee@web.com'));
$mail->setSubject('support mail');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
$mail->setBodyHtml($message)
->setFrom('abc@gty.com', 'abc')
->addTo($to, 'admin')
->setSubject($subj);
```

Here `$message` contains all table contents retrieved from `Post`.
Suggestion given by `@Pekka` is an important one.
Hope this helps you.